# Multiple versions of SQL Server Running

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, windows-7, sql-server-2012

I just did a fresh install of Windows 7, and then installed two applications, each of which use a free SQL Database as a back end. UPS Worldship installed SQL Server 2005, and "Shipworks" installed SQL Server 2012.

**Is there any (reasonably easy) way to combine it so that both databases run happily under 2012?** It seems inefficient to have both 2005 and 2012 servers running side by side.

I tried uninstalling Worldship, then uninstalling Server 2005, and re-installing Worldship, to see if it would detect the presence of Server 2012, but there was no difference.

Comment: If UPS Worldship supports SQL Server 2012 and allows you to change the connection settings then you could move the database to the SQL Server 2012 instance and change the connection settings - this seems more like a question about UPS Worldship than it does about programming.  Have you tried contacting them for support?

Comment: Voting to move this to SuperUser because it doesn't appear to be programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that these applications require the functionality of these databases.  Perhaps UPS Worldship was built, tested, and released on 2005, but it won't worry correctly on 2012.  Every database release has features that are deprecated and eventually dropped.

Theoretically, it is possible to move databases from 2005 to 2012.  First, you might need to create a backup of the 2005 database.  Restore it into the 2012 server.

Then, you will need to find the connection string and change it.  The connection string might be in an XML or text file, or in the registry, or saved somewhere in some binary format.  However, even if you do change them, and everything still works, you are likely to have "voided your warranty" and not be eligible for support.